# Akka Streams + Akka Cluster

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-cluster

I have a question about the use of Akka Streams and Akka Cluster. I'm trying to make a version of distributed word count using Akka Streams and Akka Cluster.

I would like to build an Akka Streams client that reads a text file as streaming I/O and sends the stream of words to a remote cluster. This is the code of the client:

```
final Path file = Paths.get("example.txt");
final Source<ByteString, CompletionStage<IOResult>> read = FileIO.fromPath(file);

final Source<Pair<String, Integer>, CompletionStage<IOResult>> counts =
  read
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString.fromString(" "), 256, FramingTruncation.ALLOW))
    .map(i -> i.utf8String())
    .runWith(/* send to Akka cluster */);
```

I don't understand what I have to use to send streaming data to an Akka cluster without losing the bases of Akka Streams (backpressure, etc.).

I know of the existence of Stream refs and Cluster Client but I don't understand which of them to use.

Comment: There is a way to integrate actors with akka streams: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#integrating-with-actors, though I don't think it's a good idea since, in order to preserve the the back pressure, you have to add a lot of boiler plate across your actors...

Answer (score 0):

**Direct Answer**

I don't think the functionality that you are looking for is available as of version `2.5.18`.  The [inventory of cluster functionality](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html?language=scala#higher-level-cluster-tools) doesn't list anything related to streams.

**Indirect Answer**

The computational requirements for your use case would have to be rather extreme to justify an `akka-stream` spanning multiple servers.  The amount of parallelism available in a single server is rather large given the explosion of core count on modern processors.  Therefore, each step of computation in your stream would have to require a huge amount of processor resources to justify spanning the stream across a network.

If you are truly working on such a large project then a tool like [apache spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) may better suite your needs.

Comment: I know that this use case doesn't justify the use of akka streams but i worked It as initial parte of my thesis. i use this use case only to start to use akka toolkit. Than I hope to use a more realistic and extreme use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are looking for currently exists. However, there is this similar thing called `streamRefs` which allow you to have reactive streams over the network. Take a look here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-refs.html

Comment: I have read about StreamRef but seams to be something to tie two stream over network. Instead i want to tie a single stream to  multiple stream on multiple node in a akka cluster. Now i'm using the first stream as publisher and the streams in cluster as consumer with akka Kafka streams but I don't know if It is the best solution